# Exception unhandled error in visual studio(python)

Tags: python, visual-studio, error-handling

In this code i was trying to read my stock dataset and work with that. I was converting string to float and suddenly *Exception unhandled* pop out. Can you guys help me to solve this error?

```
def dataset():

    import pandas as pd
    url = 'Place of .csv file'

    names = ['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume','OpenInt']

    dataset = pd.read_csv(url,names = names)

    low = dataset['Low'][1:]

    for i in range(len(low)):
        low[i] = float(low[i])

    return low
```

Exception unhandled error ==> low[i] = float(low[i])

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is this suppose to do??     for i in range(len(low)):
        low[i] = float(low[i])

Comment: Apparently, `low[i]` is not of the type you think it is. Without knowing your data and [what you want to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it is difficult to help you.